# How to push notifications in firebase node.js cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I want to create a function with node.js but I've got stuck at a point.

Explanation of what I want to do:

First, the function will trigger when a new document added to the path profile/{profileID}/posts/{newDocument}

the function will send a notification to all the following users. the problem comes here.

I've another collection in the profile collection which is followers and contains documents of the field followerID.

I want to take this followerID and use it as a document id to access the tokenID field with I've added to the profile document.

like this:

..(profile/followerID).get(); and then access the field value of tokenID field.

My current Code:- Index.js

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.fcmTester = functions.firestore.document('profile/{profileID}/posts/{postID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const notificationMessageData = snapshot.data();

    var x = firestore.doc('profile/{profileID}/followers/');

    var follower;

    x.get().then(snapshot => {
      follower = snapshot.followerID;
    });



    return admin.firestore().collection('profile').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            var tokens = [];

            if (snapshot.empty) {
                console.log('No Devices');
                throw new Error('No Devices');
            } else {
                for (var token of snapshot.docs) {
                    tokens.push(token.data().tokenID);
                }

                var payload = {
                    "notification": {
                        "title": notificationMessageData.title,
                        "body": notificationMessageData.title,
                        "sound": "default"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "sendername": notificationMessageData.title,
                        "message": notificationMessageData.title
                    }
                }

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        })

});
```

my firestore database explanation.

profile | profileDocuments | posts & followers | followers collection documents & posts collection documents

I have a parent collection called profile and it contains documents as any collection these documents contain a field called tokenID and that I want to access, but I will not do this for all users only for followers (the users who follwed that profile) so I've created a new collection called followers and it contains all the followers IDs, I want to take every followerID and for each id push tokenID to tokens list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you should do as follows. See the explanations below.

```
exports.fcmTester = functions.firestore.document('profile/{profileID}/posts/{postID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    
    const notificationMessageData = snapshot.data();
    const profileID = context.params.profileID;

    // var x = firestore.doc('profile/{profileID}/followers/');  //This does not point to a document since your path is composed of 3 elements

    var followersCollecRef = admin.firestore().collection('profile/' + profileID + '/followers/');  
    //You could also use Template literals `profile/${profileID}/followers/`

    return followersCollecRef.get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        var tokens = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            tokens.push(doc.data().tokenID);
        });
        
        var payload = {
            "notification": {
                "title": notificationMessageData.title,
                "body": notificationMessageData.title,
                "sound": "default"
            },
            "data": {
                "sendername": notificationMessageData.title,
                "message": notificationMessageData.title
            }
        }

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
        
    });
```

First by doing `var x = firestore.doc('profile/{profileID}/followers/');` you don't declare a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) because your path is composed of 3 elements (i.e. Collection/Doc/Collection). Note also that,in a Cloud Function, you need to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in order to read other Firestore documents/collections: So you need to do `admin.firestore()`  (`var x = firestore.doc(...)` will not work).

Secondly, you cannot get the value of `profileID` just by doing `{profileID}`: you need to use the `context` object, as follows `const profileID = context.params.profileID;`.

So, applying the above, we declare a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) `followersCollecRef` and we call the `get()` method. Then we loop over all the docs of this Collection with `querySnapshot.forEach()` to populate the `tokens` array.

The remaining part is easy and in line with your code.

---

Finally, note that since v1.0 you should initialize your Cloud Functions simple with `admin.initializeApp();`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin

---

### Update following your comments

The following Cloud Function code will lookup the Profile document of each follower and use the value of the `tokenID` field from this document.

(Note that you could also store the `tokenID` directly in the Follower document. You would duplicate data but this is quite common in the NoSQL world.)

```
exports.fcmTester = functions.firestore.document('profile/{profileID}/posts/{postID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const notificationMessageData = snapshot.data();
    const profileID = context.params.profileID;

    // var x = firestore.doc('profile/{profileID}/followers/');  //This does not point to a document but to a collectrion since your path is composed of 3 elements

    const followersCollecRef = admin.firestore().collection('profile/' + profileID + '/followers/');
    //You could also use Template literals `profile/${profileID}/followers/`

    return followersCollecRef.get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            //For each Follower document we need to query it's corresponding Profile document. We will use Promise.all()

            const promises = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                const followerDocID = doc.id;
                promises.push(admin.firestore().doc(`profile/${followerDocID}`).get());  //We use the id property of the DocumentSnapshot to build a DocumentReference and we call get() on it.
            });

            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
        .then(results => {
            //results is an array of DocumentSnapshots
            //We will iterate over this array to get the values of tokenID

            const tokens = [];
            results.forEach(doc => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        tokens.push(doc.data().tokenID);
                    } else {
                        //It's up to you to decide what you want to to do in case a Follower doc doesn't have a corresponding Profile doc
                        //Ignore it or throw an error
                    }
            });

            const payload = {
                "notification": {
                    "title": notificationMessageData.title,
                    "body": notificationMessageData.title,
                    "sound": "default"
                },
                "data": {
                    "sendername": notificationMessageData.title,
                    "message": notificationMessageData.title
                }
            }

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        });

});
```

Comment: thank you very much really helped me but in the followers collection I have the follwerID field and therefore I can use it as a document id in profile collection to get the tokenID field . if you don't mind please help me in this part

Comment: I would help you with pleasure but you need to explain very clearly what are the exact references of the different documents. In your comment you speak about the field of a "collection". It is difficult to understand exactly what is what. Please update your question with a clear explanation showing the exact paths of the different documents.

Comment: I am sorry sir, but it gives me this error : ReferenceError: querySnapshot is not defined
    at results.forEach.docSnapshot (/srv/index.js:37:17)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at followersCollecRef.get.then.then.results (/srv/index.js:36:21)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: in results.forEach

Comment: Yes, there was a typo in my answer: I've adapted it around 15 minutes ago. Please take the new code in the answer.

Comment: In my answer, at the bottom. I have modified it as I said, so just copy it again. You can see the modifications here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59228683/revisions

Comment: I am sorry for wasting your time, thank you! it worked!